# Xcode 10 doesn't support SVN (Subversion)

Tags: svn, xcode10

Installed new **Xcode 10 beta** version, Couldn't see the option for SVN in `Xcode->Preferences->Source Control`, I could see Git alone.

I guess Xcode 10 removed the SVN GUI, instead it supports only Git. Or I miss something in configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: have you find any solution for this?

Comment: If you want to use SVN + XCode, the answer is NO. You can use svnX as mentioned in the answer below. Otherwise you have to move to Git.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using svn as well. And Xcode 10 beta is removing the support for svn is really a terrible thing. But I do find a out that using git-svn is one of the solution.

- git svn clone 'svn url' 'localpath' <-> svn checkout 'svn url' 'localpath'
- git svn rebase <-> svn update
- git svn dcommit <-> svn commit

You may google for more information on this.

Now. You could using Xcode to compare codes with your local git. Then using command to update from or commit to svn.

Answer (score 2):

SVN support has unfortunately been removed. As a free alternative you can use alongside Xcode take a look at [svnX](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/svnx/html/Downloads.html). HTH

Comment: it is very not user friendly. you should visit each folder to check if an update or modification took place

Comment: @iosMentalist - If I understand your issue go to the Working Copies window, double-click (adding first if needed) your particular project, and the project window will show you the changes in whole project in a single list. To, say, commit them all you can Select All in the window and then press the Commit button. It doesn't compare to Xcode's Commit window with difference display, but it works easily enough. HTH *[Disclaimer: I have no connection with svnX other than as a user.]*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they dropped SVN support.

Found that [SnailSVN](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/snailsvn-lite-svn-for-finder/id1063090543?mt=12) is good enough - it resembles closely TortoiseSVN on Windows which is good.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is no longer supported on Xcode 10, based on [Xcode 10 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes)

. Support for Subversion has been removed. (33361671)