# How to use SVN with xcode 10

Tags: git, svn, visualsvn-server, xcode10

I have just upgraded my xcode 9 to 10, and realized that the svn support is permanently removed. My central server is setup in VisualSVN. Should I needs to move to git server and use git or is there any minimal migration step  to user VisualSVN and Git along side.

[image]

Comment: You can still use the command line **svn** client to perform SVN actions.

Comment: Also related to [Xcode 10 doesn't support SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112779/xcode-10-doesnt-support-svn-subversion).